# Resize three panels (left, center, right) in Javascript: the middle one does not resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to Javascript. Having an html, css and js file, I have 3 panels that I would like to resize (left, center, right). The left panel resizes correctly (by dragging the column border).

[image]

Now I would also like to resize the central column by dragging the right side edge of the central column (the one circled in red). This will automatically resize both the center column and the right column.

I would like that when I resize the left panel, the left panel and the central panel should move, but the right panel must remain stationary. Consequently, when I resize the right panel, then the right panel and the central panel move, but the left panel must remain still.

I think I'm doing something wrong here:

```
   let prevX = e.x;
   const leftPanel = leftPane.getBoundingClientRect();

   let prevX2 = e.x;
   const centerPanel = centerPane.getBoundingClientRect();
  
   function mousemove(e) {
     let newX = prevX - e.x;
     leftPane.style.width = leftPanel.width - newX + "px";

     let newX2 = prevX2 - e.x;
     centerPane.style.width = centerPanel.width - newX2 + "px";
   }
```

Complete code:

**index.html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pane left">
    This is the left pane.
  </div>
  
    <div class="pane center">
    This is the center pane.
    <div class="gutter"></div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="pane right">
    This is the right pane.
    <div class="gutter"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
*, *::before, *::after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
 body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #333;
  border: 6px solid #666;
  display: flex;
}

.pane {
  padding: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.left {
  
}

.center {
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  position: relative;
}

.gutter {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: col-resize;
}
```

**panel.js**

```
const leftPane = document.querySelector(".left");
const centerPane = document.querySelector(".center");
const centerPane = document.querySelector(".right");
const gutter = document.querySelector(".gutter");


function resizer(e) {
  
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
  
  let prevX = e.x;
  const leftPanel = leftPane.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  function mousemove(e) {
    let newX = prevX - e.x;
    leftPane.style.width = leftPanel.width - newX + "px";
  }
  
  function mouseup() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
    
  }
  
  
}
gutter.addEventListener('mousedown', resizer);
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need `querySelectorAll` and `gutter.forEach...` to add eventListener on both `.gutter`.
2. You can select previous panel according to the gutter you are moving.

```js
const gutters = document.querySelectorAll(".gutter");
const panes = document.querySelectorAll(".pane");
const minWidth = 200;

function resizer(e) {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);

  let prevX = e.x;
  const currentPane = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
  const currentPanel = currentPane.getBoundingClientRect();
  const prevPane = currentPane.previousElementSibling;
  const prevPanel = prevPane.getBoundingClientRect();

  function mousemove(e) {
    let newX = prevX - e.x;
    let newCurrentWidth = currentPanel.width + newX;
    let newPrevWidth = prevPanel.width - newX;
    if (newCurrentWidth < minWidth || newPrevWidth < minWidth) return;
    currentPane.style.width = newCurrentWidth + "px";
    prevPane.style.width = newPrevWidth + "px";
  }

  function mouseup() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
  }
}
gutters.forEach((gutter) => gutter.addEventListener("mousedown", resizer));
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #333;
  border: 6px solid #666;
  display: flex;
}

.pane {
  padding: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.center {
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.gutter {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: col-resize;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pane left">
    This is the left pane.
  </div>

  <div class="pane center">
    This is the center pane.
    <div class="gutter"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="pane right">
    This is the right pane.
    <div class="gutter"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your code, but there is a problem. When I resize the first column (by dragging the right edge of the left panel), both the center and right columns are resized. In short, all the columns move. I don't want this.

I would like that when I resize the first column, the third column should stay put and not resize. I would therefore like that when I resize the first column, only the left and central columns should resize.

Comment: I edit my answer, add `flex-grow: 1;` on right pane, calculate current pane's width when mousemove.

Comment: OK perfect. Thank you. A curiosity: how can I set an initial default width for each panel? So each panel has a different width. I tried with widht, but it doesn't work

Comment: If you use my solution, you can set `.left` and `.center` initial width by `width`, and `.right` will fill the rest of space.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I'm desperate. I posted a question with the same code you suggested in this answer. Having still not received a satisfactory response, I thought I'd ask if you could help me. I thought of you because the code in the new question is the same as the one you suggested. Sorry to bother you, I didn't mean to, but I'm getting discouraged. If you can help me I would be happy. If you don't want to, I understand, thanks anyway and sorry again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77776758/how-to-add-a-panel-in-javascript-that-resize-vertically-inside-another-panel

Comment: It's an interesting design, I am glad to answer that question.

Comment: Thank you. Then I await your solution. You are very kind :) Of course in case of help i will vote and accept your solution :) Sorry again and thanks

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77783975/18229259).