# How to add a panel, in Javascript, that resize vertically inside another panel?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see, i have three panels (left, center, right) that scale/resize correctly horizontally. Now i would like to insert a new panel inside the central panel.

[image]

The new panel will have to resize vertically (rising above and below). I would like to achieve this in pure Javascript (without jQuery or other libraries) as per my Javascript code. I'm new to Javascript and i'm having trouble.

I would like to get this:

[image]

P.S: Naturally the 3 vertical panels (left, center, right) must continue to move left and right horizontally, as they already move correctly with my code. I don't want the new addition of the panel to break the already functioning movement of the other panels.

This is my code:

```js
const gutters = document.querySelectorAll(".gutter");
const gutter_orizontal = document.querySelectorAll(".gutter_new");

const panes = document.querySelectorAll(".pane");
const minWidth = 200;

function resizer(e) {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);

  let prevX = e.x;
  const currentPane = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
  const currentPanel = currentPane.getBoundingClientRect();
  const prevPane = currentPane.previousElementSibling;
  const prevPanel = prevPane.getBoundingClientRect();

  function mousemove(e) {
    let newX = prevX - e.x;
    let newCurrentWidth = currentPanel.width + newX;
    let newPrevWidth = prevPanel.width - newX;
    if (newCurrentWidth < minWidth || newPrevWidth < minWidth) return;
    currentPane.style.width = newCurrentWidth + "px";
    prevPane.style.width = newPrevWidth + "px";
  }

  function mouseup() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
  }
}
gutters.forEach((gutter) => gutter.addEventListener("mousedown", resizer));
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #333;
  border: 6px solid #666;
  display: flex;
}

.pane {
  padding: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 200px;
}

.center {
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.new {
  position: relative;
}

.gutter {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.gutter_new {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: row-resize;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pane left">
    This is the left pane.
  </div>
  <div class="pane center">
    This is the center pane.
    <div class="gutter"></div>
    <div class="pane new">
      This is the new pane.
      <div class="gutter_new"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="pane right">
    This is the right pane.
    <div class="gutter"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add two classes `.gutter-v` & `.gutter-h`, `resizer()` will change `.pane`'s width or height depend on `.gutter`'s class.
2. Use `has()` selector to change `.pane` which become parent of other `.pane` to flexbox. `has()` already supported by latest firefox.
3. minHeight and minWidth is now in `.wrapper` inline style, so you can get them by js.

```js
const gutters = document.querySelectorAll(".gutter");
const panes = document.querySelectorAll(".pane");
const minWidth = document.querySelector(".wrapper").style.getPropertyValue("--min-width");
const minHeight = document.querySelector(".wrapper").style.getPropertyValue("--min-height");

function resizer(e) {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);

  //   check gutter if vertical or horizontal
  const is_vertical = e.currentTarget.classList.contains("gutter-v");
  //   get previous position (x or y depending on is_vertical)
  const prev = is_vertical ? e.x : e.y;
  //   get current pane, the parent pane of the gutter you are moving
  const currentPane = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
  const currentPanel = currentPane.getBoundingClientRect();
  //   get previous pane, when move gutter-v:
  //   if current pane is center, prev pane will be left pane
  //   if current pane is right, prev pane will be center pane
  //   left pane will never be current pane cause it don't have gutter
  const prevPane = currentPane.previousElementSibling;
  const prevPanel = prevPane.getBoundingClientRect();

  function mousemove(e) {
    // minWidth and minHeight are string ('200px' and '100px' in this case), change them to integer
    const min = parseInt(is_vertical ? minWidth : minHeight);
    // calculate distance between prev and current position
    const distance = prev - (is_vertical ? e.x : e.y);
    // calculate new width/height of current pane and prev pane
    const newCurrentSize = (is_vertical ? currentPanel.width : currentPanel.height) + distance;
    const newPrevSize = (is_vertical ? prevPanel.width : prevPanel.height) - distance;
    // if new width/height is less than min, return and don't change pane style
    if (newCurrentSize < min || newPrevSize < min) return;
    // change pane width/height depending on is_vertical
    if (is_vertical) {
      currentPane.style.width = newCurrentSize + "px";
      prevPane.style.width = newPrevSize + "px";
    } else {
      currentPane.style.height = newCurrentSize + "px";
      prevPane.style.height = newPrevSize + "px";
    }
  }

  function mouseup() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
  }
}
gutters.forEach((gutter) => gutter.addEventListener("mousedown", resizer));
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #333;
  border: 6px solid #666;
  display: flex;
}

.pane {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  /* 
  --min-width in .wrapper inline style 
  <div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;"> 
  */
  min-width: var(--min-width);
}

.pane:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.pane:has(.pane) {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pane>.pane {
  /* 
  --min-height in .wrapper inline style 
  <div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;">
  */
  min-height: var(--min-height);
}

.gutter {
  --l: 100%;
  --s: 10px;
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.gutter-v {
  width: var(--s);
  height: var(--l);
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.gutter-h {
  height: var(--s);
  width: var(--l);
  cursor: row-resize;
}


/* 
the reason I delete .right is because I use .pane:last-child to select the last pane (the bottom one or the right one)
you can keep .left and .center  to set default width and height
but it's better to use some classes like .w-250px or .h-150px, it's easier to read and reuse
*/

.w-250px {
  width: 250px;
}

.h-150px {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!-- use css variables so you only need to edit one place if you need to change min width or min height -->
<div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;">
  <div class="pane w-250px">
    This is the left pane.
  </div>
  <div class="pane">
    <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
    <div class="pane h-150px">
      This is the center pane1.
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <div class="gutter gutter-h"></div>
      This is the center pane2.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pane">
    <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
    This is the right pane.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok fine. But in the center could you remove a pane from html and js? So in the center can you just stay pane1 and pane2 please? (as per my image in the question). I'm asking you this because I'm new to Javascript and a third bread in the middle would make me confused in understanding Javascript code. Also, can you add some comments (e.g. //COMMENT) in the Javascript code to split and order the resizing of Left pane, Center pane1, Center pane2 and Right pane? Your code is great, but since I'm new to it, I'd like to understand it better. Thank you

Comment: I add comment in js code, you can easily add or remove pane in center (or in left and right if you need), now its two panes in center.

Comment: Thank you. You are very kind :) One last thing please: i see that you deleted .left, .center, .right. I used them for dimensions and set width: xx px. Now, after your changes, i only see pane. Also there is .pane>.pane {min-height: var(--min-height);} which now confuses me. QUESTION: How can I manage the width of left pane, right pane and and how can I manage the height of center pane1 and center pane2? I would like different sizes for each of them, therefore 4 different sizes. Could you add something in the css or html with which I can handle them? Thank you

Comment: I add comment in html and css.

Comment: Thank you. I read them. So if I don't want to use h-150px and w-250px, should I recreate .left, .center, .right? So set the CSS like this? .left: {width:750px}; .right: {width:700px}; .center {width:650px, height:700px}; By writing this css, could there be conflicts with your code?
​

Comment: Yes you can. But the `.right` one will fill the rest of space, its default width will decide by `.left` and `.center`

Comment: Thank you so much for all the information. I also apologize for a few too many questions. You were very kind and patient. I vote for you and accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry if I bother you again.This is the last time. I wanted to ask you if you can help me with a question about the same code. I only wrote to you because my question still concerns your code, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered you. Maybe it needs to be solved with drag events. If you can/want, I would be happy to hear from you. Of course in case of help I will vote and accept your answer. If you don't want to help me, don't worry, I apologize for the inconvenience. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77796720/dragging-to-resize-a-panel-freezes-if-i-set-the-height-to-100-of-its-contents

Answer (score 1):

You could either reuse your resizer function and give it a second parameter (such as "direction" for example).
Then in the function handle if you want to resize vertically or horizontally. Depending on the direction, you could modify either the width or the height of your element.

Then you add a new forEach loop for your handlers like this:

```
// before
gutters.forEach((gutter) => gutter.addEventListener("mousedown", resizer));

// after
gutters.forEach((gutter) => gutter.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => resizer(e, 'vertical')));
gutter_horizontal.forEach((gutter) => gutter.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => resizer(e, 'horizontal')))
```

Your function would change to something like this:

```
function resizer(e, direction) {...}
```

Within it you can then check on the direction parameter like this:

```
if (direction === 'vertical') {...}
```

Alternatively, you could also create a second resizer function for your horizontal changes. But this would create duplicated code, so I would prefer to go with the parameter in the function.

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't work. Could you show me the complete code please?

Comment: Answers from other users are also welcome. The more answers the better