# Dragging to resize a panel, in Javascript, freezes if I set the height to 100% of its contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm having trouble dragging a panel with the mouse to resize it. I thought it was a problem similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325273/make-iframe-to-fit-100-of-containers-remaining-height) on Stackoverlow, therefore solvable with `flexbox`, but by analyzing and testing the code i realized that they are not the right solutions for my case, because my case is different. Flexbox and that question don't seem to be the solution. Maybe it's a problem that concerns Javascript and not CSS.

[image]

**WHAT I WANT?** I would like to be able to drag the line of the right panel (the one indicated in the image) and resize the panel, moving it to the right or left. Inside the right panel is an `iframe`. If i only set `widht:100%` to the iframe (in the css with id `#preview`), then its resize works correctly, but when i also apply `height:100%` to the `iframe`, then it no longer works, the resize stops. I actually need the `iframe` to also have `height:100%` because i want the iframe to extend as long as the entire panel.

**WHEN DOES THE PROBLEM OCCUR?** If you drag the right panel line (the one indicated in the image) and move it from right to left, then the panel expands correctly. Subsequently, after having enlarged the panel, if you try to shrink it (dragging the line from right to left) and bring it back to its initial size, then everything freezes.

**SOLUTION ATTEMPTS.** I tried various (useless) solutions with css, i also tried using `flexbox` and i also tried the solutions to the Stackoverflow question i was talking about above at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325273/make-iframe-to-fit-100-of-containers-remaining-height), but it's all useless. The problem doesn't appear to be flexbox. Flexbox seems useless. So I'm thinking the problem might be the Javascript code i use to resize. I add: The comment of the kind user who suggested [drag events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dragstart_event) is interesting. I tried, but it doesn't work (maybe my mistake, I don't know)

**P.S:** I would like to continue using pure JavaScript, I would not like to use jQuery. Also I would like to extend the iframe to the container using height:100% with percentage and not height: ? px using px

Can any of you help me please? Thank you

```js
const gutters = document.querySelectorAll(".gutter");
const panes = document.querySelectorAll(".pane");
const minWidth = document.querySelector(".wrapper").style.getPropertyValue("--min-width");
const minHeight = document.querySelector(".wrapper").style.getPropertyValue("--min-height");

function resizer(e) {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);

  //   check gutter if vertical or horizontal
  const is_vertical = e.currentTarget.classList.contains("gutter-v");
  //   get previous position (x or y depending on is_vertical)
  const prev = is_vertical ? e.x : e.y;
  //   get current pane, the parent pane of the gutter you are moving
  const currentPane = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
  const currentPanel = currentPane.getBoundingClientRect();
  //   get previous pane, when move gutter-v:
  //   if current pane is center, prev pane will be left pane
  //   if current pane is right, prev pane will be center pane
  //   left pane will never be current pane cause it don't have gutter
  const prevPane = currentPane.previousElementSibling;
  const prevPanel = prevPane.getBoundingClientRect();

  function mousemove(e) {
    // minWidth and minHeight are string ('200px' and '100px' in this case), change them to integer
    const min = parseInt(is_vertical ? minWidth : minHeight);
    // calculate distance between prev and current position
    const distance = prev - (is_vertical ? e.x : e.y);
    // calculate new width/height of current pane and prev pane
    const newCurrentSize = (is_vertical ? currentPanel.width : currentPanel.height) + distance;
    const newPrevSize = (is_vertical ? prevPanel.width : prevPanel.height) - distance;
    // if new width/height is less than min, return and don't change pane style
    if (newCurrentSize < min || newPrevSize < min) return;
    // change pane width/height depending on is_vertical
    if (is_vertical) {
      currentPane.style.width = newCurrentSize + "px";
      prevPane.style.width = newPrevSize + "px";
    } else {
      currentPane.style.height = newCurrentSize + "px";
      prevPane.style.height = newPrevSize + "px";
    }
  }

  function mouseup() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
  }
}
gutters.forEach((gutter) => gutter.addEventListener("mousedown", resizer));
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #333;
  border: 6px solid #666;
  display: flex;
}

.pane {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  /* 
      --min-width in .wrapper inline style 
      <div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;"> 
      */
  min-width: var(--min-width);
}

.pane:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.pane:has(.pane) {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pane>.pane {
  /* 
      --min-height in .wrapper inline style 
      <div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;">
      */
  min-height: var(--min-height);
}

.gutter {
  --l: 100%;
  --s: 10px;
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.gutter-v {
  width: var(--s);
  height: var(--l);
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.gutter-h {
  height: var(--s);
  width: var(--l);
  cursor: row-resize;
}

.left {
  width: 600px;
}

.center_container {
  width: 650px;
}

.center1 {
  height: 700px;
}

#preview {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #991717;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;">
  <div class="pane left">
    This is the left pane.
  </div>
  <div class="pane center_container">
    <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
    <div class="pane center1">
      This is the center pane1
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <div class="gutter gutter-h"></div>
      This is the center pane2.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pane">
    <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
    <iframe id="preview"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would consider using the drag events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dragstart_event

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I tried using dragstart and dragend, but it doesn't work. Of course, thank you for the suggestion. Maybe I did something wrong. If you want/can, could you show me the solution using drag event please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `iframe` is another page, when the mouse on `iframe` the `mousemove` event is interrupted.

You can add `pointer-events: none;` to prevent this issue.

```css
#preview.resizing {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Then add/remove `.resizing` when move start and end by js.

```js
const iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
...
// in resizer()
iframes.forEach((iframe) => iframe.classList.add("resizing"));

// in mouseup()
iframes.forEach((iframe) => iframe.classList.remove("resizing"));
```

```js
const gutters = document.querySelectorAll(".gutter");
const panes = document.querySelectorAll(".pane");
const minWidth = document.querySelector(".wrapper").style.getPropertyValue("--min-width");
const minHeight = document.querySelector(".wrapper").style.getPropertyValue("--min-height");
const iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");

function resizer(e) {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
  //   add .resizing when mousedown
  iframes.forEach((iframe) => iframe.classList.add("resizing"));

  //   check gutter if vertical or horizontal
  const is_vertical = e.currentTarget.classList.contains("gutter-v");
  //   get previous position (x or y depending on is_vertical)
  const prev = is_vertical ? e.x : e.y;
  //   get current pane, the parent pane of the gutter you are moving
  const currentPane = e.currentTarget.parentNode;
  const currentPanel = currentPane.getBoundingClientRect();
  //   get previous pane, when move gutter-v:
  //   if current pane is center, prev pane will be left pane
  //   if current pane is right, prev pane will be center pane
  //   left pane will never be current pane cause it don't have gutter
  const prevPane = currentPane.previousElementSibling;
  const prevPanel = prevPane.getBoundingClientRect();

  function mousemove(e) {
    // minWidth and minHeight are string ('200px' and '100px' in this case), change them to integer
    const min = parseInt(is_vertical ? minWidth : minHeight);
    // calculate distance between prev and current position
    const distance = prev - (is_vertical ? e.x : e.y);
    // calculate new width/height of current pane and prev pane
    const newCurrentSize = (is_vertical ? currentPanel.width : currentPanel.height) + distance;
    const newPrevSize = (is_vertical ? prevPanel.width : prevPanel.height) - distance;
    // if new width/height is less than min, return and don't change pane style
    if (newCurrentSize < min || newPrevSize < min) return;
    // change pane width/height depending on is_vertical
    if (is_vertical) {
      currentPane.style.width = newCurrentSize + "px";
      prevPane.style.width = newPrevSize + "px";
    } else {
      currentPane.style.height = newCurrentSize + "px";
      prevPane.style.height = newPrevSize + "px";
    }
  }

  function mouseup() {
    // remove .resizing when mouseup
    iframes.forEach((iframe) => iframe.classList.remove("resizing"));
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
  }
}
gutters.forEach((gutter) => gutter.addEventListener("mousedown", resizer));
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #333;
  border: 6px solid #666;
  display: flex;
}

.pane {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  /* 
      --min-width in .wrapper inline style 
      <div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;"> 
      */
  min-width: var(--min-width);
}

.pane:last-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.pane:has(.pane) {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pane>.pane {
  /* 
      --min-height in .wrapper inline style 
      <div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;">
      */
  min-height: var(--min-height);
}

.gutter {
  --l: 100%;
  --s: 10px;
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.gutter-v {
  width: var(--s);
  height: var(--l);
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.gutter-h {
  height: var(--s);
  width: var(--l);
  cursor: row-resize;
}

.left {
  width: 600px;
}

.center_container {
  width: 650px;
}

.center1 {
  height: 700px;
}

#preview {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #991717;
  border: 0;
}

#preview.resizing {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="--min-width: 200px;--min-height: 100px;">
  <div class="pane left">
    This is the left pane.
  </div>
  <div class="pane center_container">
    <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
    <div class="pane center1">
      This is the center pane1
    </div>
    <div class="pane">
      <div class="gutter gutter-h"></div>
      This is the center pane2.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="pane">
    <div class="gutter gutter-v"></div>
    <iframe id="preview"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Great! Thank you very much :) A curiosity: could drag events have also solved the problem? I am new to Javascript. I tried drag events, but it doesn't work, I don't know if it's my mistake or if drag events isn't suitable for what I need to do (with much esteem and respect for the user who recommended it to me)

Comment: You can use drag event to make same result as mouse event in this case, but drag event will be interrupted in `iframe` too.

Comment: This does not work on touch (or handheld) devices. `pointer` events might work better.